# Get UTF-8 html content with Node's http.get

Tags: html, node.js, http, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to pull the html content of a given url and the origin content encoding is utf-8. I get the html of the page but the text whitin the html elemnts are returned in bad format (question marks).

This is what I do:

```
var parsedPath = url.parse(path);
var options = {
    host: parsedPath.host,
    path: parsedPath.path,
    headers: {
        'Accept-Charset' : 'utf-8',
    }
}

http.get(options, function (res) {
    var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).on("error", function () {
    callback(null);
});
```

How can I enforce the encoding of the returned data?

Thanks

Comment: A client can't force a server to return data in any particular format. It can tell it that it only accepts data in a particular format and then the server can choose which format to send back … or it can ignore the information entirely.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, so the header I use is needless. How can I encode the data instead? when using postman to get the html with GET call the data is well written so I assume there's a way to achieve it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`setEncoding()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablesetencodingencoding) method like this:

```js
http.get(options, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```