# Force plain text encoding with node https get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, http-headers, stackexchange-api

#### Problem

Related to [Get UTF-8 html content with Node's http.get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27998950/1366033) - but that answer isn't working for me.

I'm trying to call the [Stack Overflow API questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=total&site=stackoverflow&run=true) endpoint:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?site=stackoverflow&filter=total
```

Which should return the following JSON response:

```json
{"total":21951385}
```

#### Example Code

I'm using the [`https`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) node module to submit a [`get`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsgeturl-options-callback) request like this:

```
const getRequest = (url: string) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options: RequestOptions = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'text/*',
            'Accept-Encoding':'identity',
            'Accept-Charset' : 'utf8',
        }
    }

    const req = get(url, options, (res) => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        let responseBody = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => responseBody += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => resolve(responseBody));
    });

    req.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    req.end();
})
```

And then invoking it like this:

```
const questionsUrl = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?&site=stackoverflow&filter=total'
const resp = await getRequest(questionsUrl)
console.log(resp)
```

However, I get the response:

```
▼�
�V*�/I�Q�22�454�0�♣��♥‼���↕
```

#### What I've Tried

I've tried doing several variations of the following:

- I'm calling [`setEncoding`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablesetencodingencoding) to `utf8` on the stream
- I've set the [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header to `text/*` - which

  > Provides a text MIME type, but without a subtype
- I've set the [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header to `identity` -  which

  > Indicates the identity function (that is, without modification or compression)

This code also works just fine with pretty much any other API server, for example using the following url:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
```

But the StackOverlow API works anywhere else I've tried it, so there must be a way to instruct node how to execute it.

Comment: Looks like perhaps gzip compression.  Look at ALL the response headers to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use an http library that supports both promises and gzip built in.  My current favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).   `http.get()` is like the least featured http request library anywhere. You really don't have to write all this yourself.  Here's what your entire code would look like with the got() library:

```
const got = require('got');

function getRequest(url) {
    return got(url).json();
}
```

This library handles all these things you need for you automatically:

1. Promises
2. JSON conversion
3. Gzip decoding
4. 2xx status detection (other status codes like 404 are turned into a promise rejection which your code does not do).

And, it has many, many other useful features for other general use.  The days of coding manually with `http.get()` should be long over.  No need to rewrite code that has already been written and well-tested for you.

FYI, there's a list of very capable http libraries here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143.  You can pick the one that has the API you like the best.

Answer (score 0):

### Response Header - Content-Encoding - Gzip

As [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139545/force-plain-text-encoding-with-node-https-get-request#comment123986899_70139545) pointed out - looks like the server isn't respecting the `Accept-Encoding` value being passed and returning a gzipped response none-the-less.

[image: Postman Headers Screenshot]

### Unzipping Response

According to the answer on [How do I ungzip (decompress) a NodeJS request's module gzip response body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12148948/1366033), you can unzip like this:

```js
import { get } from 'https'
import { createGunzip } from 'zlib'

const getRequest = (url: string) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = get(url, (res) => {
        const buffer: string[] = [];

        if (!res.headers['content-encoding']?.includes('gzip')) {
            console.log('utf8')
            res.on('data', (chunk) => buffer.push(chunk));
            res.on('end', () => resolve(buffer.join("")))
        } else {
            console.log('gzip')
            const gunzip = createGunzip();
            res.pipe(gunzip);
            gunzip.on('data', (data) => buffer.push(data.toString()))
            gunzip.on("end", () => resolve(buffer.join("")))
            gunzip.on("error", (e) => reject(e))
        }
    });

    req.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    req.end();
})
```

Comment: Or you could just use an http library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) that supports promises (built-in) and gzip.  `http.get()` is like the least featured http request library anywhere.  You really don't have to write all this yourself.

Comment: Yeah, Identity is not going to fly .... [*According to the HTTP specification identity is a valid Accept-Encoding and should instruct the server to not use compression. This is where our luck runs out as the Stack Exchange server is non-compliant here. It simply falls back to its preferred default compression: gzip. I think SE should return a 406 Not Acceptable in this case, but meh.*](https://stackapps.com/a/9217)